# Pipe symbol before command in "open"

Tags: ruby

I stumbled over the following line of code

```
open("|cd lib && /opt/jruby/bin/jruby jasper_pdf.rb") { |input| open("log/jasper_pdf.log", "w") { |f| f.write(input.read) } }
```

What is the pipe symbol before the cd command for?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby documentation for [`Kernel#open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-open) says:

> If path starts with a pipe character ("|"), a subprocess is created,
>   connected to the caller by a pair of pipes. The returned IO object may
>   be used to write to the standard input and read from the standard
>   output of this subprocess.

In your case it is used to log the output of the process spawned by the command `/opt/jruby/bin/jruby jasper_pdf.rb` to the file `log/jasper_pdf.log`.

It is roughly equivalent to use the [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) module like this:

```
require 'open3'
Open3.popen2e('cd lib && /opt/jruby/bin/jruby jasper_pdf.rb') do |_, output, _|
  open('log/jasper_pdf.log', 'w') do |f|
    f.write(output.read)
  end
end
```